# Query to get latest version if any or just the document otherwise

Tags: mysql, join

I have two table as `Documents` and `Revisions`

**Document table**

```
+--------+--------------------+
| DataID |    Description     |
+--------+--------------------+
|      1 | This is document 1 |
|      2 | This is document 2 |
|      3 | This is document 3 |
|      4 | This is document 4 |
|      5 | This is document 5 |  
+--------+--------------------+
```

**Revisions table**

```
+--------+---------+-----------+
| DataID | Version |   State   |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|      1 |       1 | Published |
|      2 |       1 | Published |
|      3 |       1 | ?         |
|      3 |       2 | Published |
|      4 |       1 | Published |
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

**Required Output**

```
+--------+--------------------+---------+
| DataID |    Description     | Version |
+--------+--------------------+---------+
|      1 | This is document 1 | 1       |
|      2 | This is document 2 | 1       |
|      3 | This is document 3 | 2       |
|      4 | This is document 4 | 1       |
|      5 | This is document 5 | N/A     |
+--------+--------------------+---------+
```

My Query:

```
SELECT d.*, h.version 
FROM documents d 
LEFT revisions h 
   ON h.dataID=d.dataID 
LEFT JOIN ( 
           SELECT dataID, MAX(version) as version 
           FROM revisions 
           GROUP BY dataID 
         ) dh 
    ON dh.dataID=h.dataID 
    AND dh.version=h.version 
    AND h.state='Published'
```

Problem with this left join it will also list the `version 1` of the `docid 3` with `state ?` whereas, I only want the Published Versions if there are any, otherwise, just list list document with version as NULL.

**EDIT:**
Please note that I would also like **all the columns data** from `revision` data if it finds the entry and not just the **version number**
Can anyone help?

Comment: It woudn't matter even if we put state!=? because it is using left join and would still display it even if the condition isn't met :/

Answer (score 3):

By filtering on `h.state` from the `WHERE` clause, you are implicitly converting your outer join to an inner one; you should instead place that condition in the join criteria:

```
SELECT   d.*, MAX(h.Version)
FROM     documents d LEFT JOIN revisions h
      ON h.DataID = d.DataID
     AND h.state  = 'Published'
GROUP BY DataID
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f09d/1/0).

Comment: Thanks for the query. Just wondering wouldn't I lose the row from revision table with highest version because of the Group By in the end? I might need other columns data for the record with highest version

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT d.*, dh.version FROM document d 
LEFT JOIN ( 
           SELECT dataID, MAX(version) as version, state
           FROM revisions 
           GROUP BY dataID,version 
         ) dh 
    ON dh.dataID=d.dataID 
    AND dh.state='Published';
```

Here's a [**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab3d9/3).

Comment: What is the difference with your query and @eggyal's? 
Looks like your query is resource intensive as it is groupding twice?